# Pager.js + History.js + Require.js - "Unable to get property 'bind' of undefined or null reference"

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, requirejs, history.js, pagerjs

I'm setting up a new Knockout web app using Require.js, Pager.js, and History.js.  I've set up my initialization [according to the docs](http://pagerjs.com/demo/#!/navigation/setup), but I'm receiving an "Unable to get property 'bind' of undefined or null reference" error from Pager.js when I call `pager.startHistoryJs()`.

Here's my Require.js config:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'knockout': '/scripts/lib/knockout-3.2.0',
        'jquery': '/scripts/lib/jquery-1.11.2.min',
        'text': '/scripts/lib/text',
        'pager': '/scripts/lib/pager.min',
        'history': '/scripts/lib/history'
    },
    shim: {
        'pager': ['jquery', 'knockout'],
        'history': ['jquery', 'pager', 'knockout'],
    },
    waitSeconds: 0
});
```

And here's my Require.js initialization script:

```
require(['knockout', 'viewmodel/appViewModel', 'jquery', 'pager', 'history', 'lib/domReady!'], function (ko, appViewModel, $, pager) {
    pager.useHTML5history = true;
    pager.Href5.history = History;
    var viewModel = new appViewModel();
    pager.extendWithPage(viewModel);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    pager.startHistoryJs();
});
```

[Here's the line in Pager.js](https://github.com/finnsson/pagerjs/blob/master/pager.js#L1497-L1500) (line 1497) that is throwing the error:

```
// Bind to StateChange Event
pager.Href5.history.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function () {
    var relativeUrl = pager.Href5.history.getState().url.replace(pager.Href5.history.getBaseUrl(), '');
    goTo(relativeUrl);
});
```

What piece am I missing?  I haven't been able to find much relevant info on this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting is consistent with loading History.js without an adapter loaded. If I look at the code in [`history.js`](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/blob/master/scripts/uncompressed/history.js), I see that if there is no adapter available, the `init` function silently returns `false` and History.js is not initialized.

I would suggest loading the [jQuery adapter](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/blob/master/scripts/uncompressed/history.adapter.jquery.js) and making `history` dependent on it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the `History` (and probably something for `lib/domReady!`) argument in your require function.

```
require(['knockout', 'viewmodel/appViewModel', 'jquery', 'pager', 'history', 'lib/domReady!'], function (ko, appViewModel, $, pager, History, domReady) {
    pager.useHTML5history = true;
    pager.Href5.history = History;
    var viewModel = new appViewModel();
    pager.extendWithPage(viewModel);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    pager.startHistoryJs();
});
```